# using js Object to add dynamically a Decorator to a property

Tags: javascript, angular

As the question says, how can i add a Decorator dynamically  to a property in an already created javascript object? I already have the reference to the javascript object and know how to assign properties and funcions to an object via

```
Object.assign()
```

I dont think its very relevant but the decorators im using are the normal angular 2.

Comment: What's the use-case you're trying to solve. It might be more clear to use a function instead of a decorator if you're trying to change something dynamically.

Comment: Im trying to create creating dynamic components on angular 2, and the decorators i want to use are "@Input" and "@Output". I saw that i can create dynamic components with ng-dynamic-component  (i also saw that i can define component class at fly like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507831/1546652 )